# How to properly use table-valued functions?

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I have a table which has an `nvarchar` column. The strings stored in this `nvarchar` column contain numbers which I need to extract. There is a table-valued `RegexMatches` function existing in my database that I can use to do this (it'll return a list of matches for the number pattern).

**My Requirement:**

This table-valued function has to be applied to this column in each row of the table. I cannot store the intermediate results anywhere (meaning function to row 1 - store - apply function to row 2 - store) because I don't know how many records will be there and there may well be 100s. At the end of the procedure, I should have a temporary table where all these numbers extracted from all rows are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [CROSS APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). See further example [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/).